# How can Jesus rule the earth during the second coming, if he is only in Jerusalem?

Tags: global-christianity, new-earth, kingdom-of-god, sovereignty

I don't understand, how Jesus comes down in the clouds and rules on the mount of olives, how can the people in other countries see him? I know the clouds all will see him, but once he actually steps on earth, how will I see him or be with him? Do we all go to Jerusalem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to christianity.stackexchange. If you have not already done so, I hope you will take the [tour] and see what kind of questions work well on this site. As it stands, you seem to be asking for the Truth about the anticipated second coming, for which there are many opinions.  To avoid this question being closed as out of scope, you could ask the teaching of a particular Christian denomination on this question, or ask the biblical basis for believing that Jesus will rule the earth from the Mount of Olives.

Comment: @Hallie  Your innocent curiosity is endearing, refreshing. Curiosity is a wonderful conductor ;-) (**Hab_2:14**)  For the earth shall be filled with the knowledge of the glory of the LORD, as the waters cover the sea.

Comment: @Nathaniel.  Is there not something, that can be done to get this question opened? I have been roaming questions to try to get some feel for how questions are being evaluated. I am not here to stir anything up. I will even delete my answer to prove it, but I have seen some questions that are absolutely, absurd compared to this; allowed to be quibbled over, and remain busy with speculation. I'm just not quite getting it yet I guess. In my opinion, whatever that may be worth, this is the most important, new question, on the site help me understand this, please. I won't attempt to edit it, no.

Answer (score 2):

Put aside the question of whether the Jerusalem which Jesus will enter and rule from is:

1) The Jerusalem we know (but fixed up)

2) A new physical city that descends fully built from Heaven, as described in Revelation

3) An image of the Church, where the people of God are the walls and buildings to be inhabited.

*How can Jesus be seen by the world?*

1) Television and the internet, via TVs, cell phones, tablets and watches which are in the possession of most people today.

2) **Supernatural means**. If man is capable of creating the internet, God is capable of even greater marvels.

*How can Jesus rule the world?*

1) **Delegation**. At his disposal, Jesus has:

a. angels. Matthew 26:53 says:

> Do you think I cannot call on my Father, and he will at once put at my
>   disposal more than twelve legions of angels?

b. the church, whom he promised will judge the world. The apostles will sit on thrones. 1 Corinthians 6:2 says:

> Or do you not know that the Lord’s people will judge the world? And if
>   you are to judge the world, are you not competent to judge trivial
>   cases?

Luke 22:29-30 says:

> And I confer on you a kingdom, just as my Father conferred one on me,
>   so that you may eat and drink at my table in my kingdom and sit on
>   thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

2) **Action at a distance**. In Matthew 8, Jesus heals a centurion's servant while that servant was sick in bed miles away. He does not need to be physically present to accomplish the Father's will.

Comment: The question was broad in scope, this does a pretty good job of covering most points, without too much personal insertion. I haven't had a chance to put togeather my own response yet, but the OP drew me out on this particular point(s); "...how will I see him or be with him?" Precious. (not to be wasted or treated carelessly.) +1 :-)